# Can I say "if you have questions"?

Tags: word-usage

I know I can say "if you have any questions, ...". 
I wonder if "any" can be omitted here.

Comment: Yes, it can be omitted.

Comment: Sherlock goes as far as 'You have questions ...'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Can't tell if that comment is tongue-in-cheek, but in Sherlock's case, it's an assertion. An utterly, smugly, confident one.

Comment: Utterly, smugly confident? Sherlock? (This time, with question marks – though they should probably have scare quotes.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. 'Any' can be omitted without loss of semantic intention.

This is because ***any*** is sometimes used as an 'emphasizing adverb', and in this context, it's most likely an adverbial emphasizer.

Cheers.